# Detect Client Real IP from Inside of running Container in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I'm running multiple microservices into Kubernetes and I need to know the client real IP that sent the request to our gateway microservice to show that in UI dashboard. I use Flannel as my overlay network inside my cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the article "Create an External Load Balancer" and especially the section
[Preserving the client source IP](https://superuser.com/questions/1509498/detect-client-real-ip-from-inside-of-running-container-in-kubernetes).

You need at least version 1.7, and set to `"externalTrafficPolicy": "Local"`
on your Service spec.

Comment: Tnx it works for me.
Ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/#preserving-the-client-source-ip